# Matching a click element with corresponding hidden project div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing a quick function in javascript that interacts with wp in a set of posts that are hidden and shown when I click an element that corresponds to its matched href="#element".

Function would run like so:

1) You click one of the dynamically added post titles where it has a href value of the post title in the  tag for it.

2) The corresponding hidden project under it with an id that matches the href value of the dynamically added elements above to basically show it and hide the previous child project.

Now I am trying to do this with pure javascript alone but its beginning to get really messy and long winded. I wondered if there was a good tool in the jquery api to aid in this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please show what you have including markup and code so we may better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in jQuery you could:

```
<h1 class="buttonHeader" data-divider="#dividerId1">Test</h1>
<h1 class="buttonHeader" data-divider="#dividerId2">Test 2</h1>
<div class="myDivider" id="dividerId1"><p>Content</p></div> <!-- Not sure what href is used for? -->
<div class="myDivider" id="dividerId2"><p>Content 2</p></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1.buttonHeader').click(function() {
        // Get data attribute from clicked header
        var correspondingDiv = $(this).attr('data-divider');
        // Hide any open 'myDivider' dividers
        $('.myDivider').hide();
        // Display the corresponding divider
        $(correspondingDiv).show();
    })
})
```

I don't really understand why you're using the href attribute.

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBuaq/1/).

Edit: I've removed the loop as it wasn't necessary.

Comment: I suppose it was a way of trying to get something into the url as later on I may need to add hash history etc for back button states! Just a quick one, $(correspondingDiv).show; will this work in an alternative way? So will it switch between each div simultaneously?

Comment: What happens here is when you click a H1 element (I'm assuming that's what you're using for post titles) this first pulls the element's "data-divider" content (as opposed to href, as this isn't a valid H1 attribute). It then loops through and hides all other dividers with the "myDivider" class (assuming your posts all have similar classes). It finally displays the divider with the ID contained within the data-divider attribute. So if you clicked on a heading with data-divider="#banana", the divider with ID "banana" would be shown.

Comment: On second thoughts the loop isn't actually necessary, calling .hide() will hide all elements with that specific class. I've edited my above post.

Comment: Hey James, I had a look at this. It works well on most things but when it comes to trying it on a div that is in a different container it does not seem to work. It shows the first one but then when you click on another it sets them all to display none. Have you any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Ah I assumed you wanted it to only show one at a time. I'm on my phone at the moment so can't test it, but I believe you can use `$(correspondingDiv).prev().hide();` instead to hide it. :)